# When wouldn't I want to protect a page from CSRF?

Tags: csrf

I am trying to use [the csrf guard project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_CSRFGuard_Project).

When wouldn't I want to protect a page from cross-site request forgeries (there is an option for protected and unprotected pages)?

Comment: More appropriate for security SO

Comment: The obvious one is when you want the page to be called cross-site. E.g., if the page forms part of your public API.

Answer (score 0):

In general the only reason why you wouldn't want csrf protection is because adding it breaks part of your website. Sometimes this might be because a specific page already has a different type of csrf protection on it.